# Maven sets activeByDefault, but it is invalid

Tags: maven

I set activeByDefault, but it doesn't work

I'm using spring-boot and maven

```xml
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <profileActive>local</profileActive>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <profileActive>dev</profileActive>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <profileActive>prod</profileActive>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

As for the pom configuration, I expect to use the local profile, but it USES prod:

```
2019-08-07 10:27:11.640  INFO 31432 --- [           main] i.g.s.SpringBootPlusApplication          : Starting SpringBootPlusApplication on cxs15313 with PID 31432 (C:\Users\15313\Desktop\springboot-plus\spring-boot-plus\target\classes started by lafeier in C:\Users\15313\Desktop\springboot-plus\spring-boot-plus)
2019-08-07 10:27:11.648  INFO 31432 --- [           main] i.g.s.SpringBootPlusApplication          : The following profiles are active: prod
2019-08-07 10:27:14.094  INFO 31432 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2019-08-07 10:27:14.098  INFO 31432 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `profileActive` has the value `prod` which activates the profile (setting `activeByDefault` to false does not prevent that).